# Increasing the size of a div

Tags: html, css, image, sass, margin

I'm trying to move some picture to the left of a table, which would not be a problem using `class="pull-left"` or `float: left;`. The problem is that whenever I use these, there is no way for me to change the distance between the two. I figured it's because the div these two are inside of is too small, so I'm trying to find a way to increase the size of the div so I can adjust margin and padding. I'd also like to move the picture a bit downwards, which also does not work because of the `pull-left` and the `float:left`.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div style="marging: 5%; display:inline-block;">
        <img class="pull-left" src="some picture" alt="Öffnungszeiten">

        <table class="wpTbOeffnungszeiten">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Headline</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr>  

            <tr><th colspan="2">Headline</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                <td>Some text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
background-image: url("some image");

.wpTbOeffnungszeiten {
    margin: 5%;
}

th {
    color: $red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: set height is auto

Answer (score 0):

With a class like `.pull-left` I assume you are integrating Bootstrap into your project, but that CSS is not present in your example code.  Running with that assumption though, adding `.pull-right` to your `<table>` and providing a valid `width` for your parent `<div>` (which has an inline style of `display: inline-block`) should resolve the issue.

Check your spelling as well, that same inline style has a typo for your `margin`